# Issue getting mysqli_query to execute

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I have written the following function in PHP that has a `mysqli_query` in it that runs without any errors or exceptions. However, the `INSERT INTO` statement or `$insert` variable doesn't seem to be working as expected and I can't figure it out. I realize that posting only a portion of the code might make it difficult to ascertain why it is not working, but I am really looking for confirmation that there are no errors in this function.

Do I need to utilize `mysqli_real_escape_string` for every url provided? I tried altering `$website` to `$_website` to account for this, but it returned nothing.

Just really trying to figure out if there's anything I'm doing wrong here that's prevent the SQL query to work. It returns no error which is making it hard to debug. Thanks in advance!

```
$jp = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "password", "mydatabase");

if (!$jp) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}



function create_distributor( $new_user_id ) {
  $errors = new WP_Error();
  $error=false;
  $errorMsg='';
  $logo=true;
  $name=addslashes(htmlentities($_REQUEST['name']));
  $contact=addslashes(htmlentities($_REQUEST['contact_info']));
  $user_info = get_userdata( $new_user_id );

  $website = $_POST['website'];
  if (stripos($website, "http://") !== 0)   //doesn't start with http:// ? , then add it
      $website = "http://" . $website; 
  // $_website = mysqli_real_escape_string($jp, $website); // THIS DOESNT RETURN ANYTHING
  $subdir = $user_info->user_nicename; // use nicename because user_login is obfuscated as unverified
  $distribpath = 'http://ghq.com/dhdq/'.$subdir;
  $ga_code = 'UA-15331916-1'; //default GA code
  $logo = 'http://ghq.com/wp-content/themes/CAG/img/ghlogo.jpg'; //default png logo

  if(!isset($_REQUEST['name']) || $_REQUEST['name']=='')
  {
    $error=true;
    $errors->add('Distributor Name is required', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>:Distrubutor\'s name was not provided.'));
  }
  if($error)
  {
    return($errorMsg);
  }


  $insert="INSERT INTO distributor (id, name, contact, logo, path, subdir, website, ga_code) VALUES ('".$new_user_id."','".$name."','".$contact."','".$logo."','".$distribpath."','".$subdir."','".$website."','".$ga_code."')";
//   var_dump($insert); 

        // The var_dump print out above is the following SQL Command which if copied and pasted 
    in phpmyadmin works fine: string(252) "INSERT INTO distributor (id, name, contact, 
logo, path, subdir, website, ga_code) VALUES ('1748','test24','','http://ghq.com/wp-content/themes/CAG/img/ghlogo.jpg',
                'http://ghq.com/dhdq/test24','test24','','UA-15331916-1')"




  mysqli_query($jp, $insert);
  if ( false===$insert ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($jp));
}
  else {
    echo 'done.';
  }
  if($error)
  {
    return $errors;
  }
  else
  {
    return($id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting backticks around your field names in your queries.

Comment: I've tried with backticks and without backticks for the field names. The reason they are off is because when you pasted the query into myphpadmin it threw errors. I removed them so this query would execute exactly like it should if I run it in phpmyadmin. It's weird that it works in phpmyadmin but not here

Comment: Well that's a debug start point - if when you echo out the SQL from the code and use it in PHPmyadmin and it works , then you know your SQL is likely ok. Check the error log, and if nothing there then it's likely down to the logic in your code. Additionally, can you expand on "*insert doesn't seem to be working*" - in what way? does nothing? also just to be sure you can try outputting sql errors (eg `mysqli_error()`  just to make sure your SQL and queries are ok

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see straight off is you are checking your sql variable instead of the query result.

```
mysqli_query($jp, $insert);
if ( false===$insert ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($jp));
}
  else {
    echo 'done.';
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($jp, $insert);
if (!$result) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($jp));
}else {
    echo 'done.';
}
```

Also whats $jp? it doesn't look like you have assigned it anything. Make sure this is the variable that has your mysqli_connect on it. With your question regarding mysqli_real_escape_string, you should really be utilizing mysqli prepared statements as well. All user input should be sanitized.

Comment: Hey Second2None, thanks for your reply. I have edited my post to include $jp which is just the mysql connection made to my database. After updating my code to what you have proposed, I did receive an error warning but it did not print out anything after `error:`. Any idea if I cn get any more info of why this error is occurring or why `mysqli_error` isn't working in this case?

Comment: Change mysqli_error($jp) to $jp->error; and see if it produces an error. You might have misspelt a column name or possibly not set any defaults when setting up your table (depending on what versions you are running).